# order firestore data by timestamp and limit to last (10)

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have this list of messages in firestore and i need to query the last 7 messages by the firestore timestamp
I have this

```
function showMessage(doc){
let div = document.createElement('div');
let message = document.createElement('span');

div.setAttribute('message-id', doc.id);
message.textContent = doc.data().message;

div.appendChild(message);

innerDiv.appendChild(div);
}
```

Function to fetch messages

```
    function fetchMessage(){    
    dbRef= 
 db.collection("user").doc("eF1RFw3FVAO3LFJ8ORrf7oJPyR13").collection('messages').orderBy("dbTime", "asc").limit(7);
        dbRef.get().then((snapshot) =>{
            snapshot.docs.forEach(doc =>{
                showMessage(doc);
            });
        });
    }
```

what is happening with this however is that it gets the first 7 messages recorded first, instead of the first last messages ordered by time.
Thinking of a chat experience these query fetches the very first messages only, that were last recorded, say last week and leaves the rest, the recent ones, which is wrong. This does not make sense in a chat since we need the first last (7) messages.

What this gives is the below picture
where hello 12 is the most recent message. Which should be at the bottom then 11 at top of it. How can i reorder this to make a good experience

[image: the]

Comment: How about using `"desc"`?

Comment: "desc" actually works but now the most recent message appears at the top of the container and last recent at the bottom which is absurd. Does this mean my other code is flawed. the one that renders the messages

Comment: Use then `desc` and reorder the messages client side.